# Changing Colours of Leaflet Map

Tags: leaflet, react-leaflet, r-leaflet, leaflet.draw

I wonder if and how it is possible to change the color of the map (individual countries, backgrounds and lines) in Leaflet?

I have simply created the basic code of a leaflet map as specified in the Quick Start Guide.

Comment: can you provide code or snippet?